# Weird behavior with JQuery UI drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Forgive me for my lack of experience with JQuery UI, however, I am developing a 2 player web based chess engine in JavaScript and have decided to get rid of point and click and go with a more user friendly drag and drop feature for non mobile users. The issue I am having will most likely be apparent to someone that uses JQuery UI a lot. Before I go into details here's a look at the code:

```
$(function(){

    //piece is an img
    $(".piece").mousedown(function() {

        currentPieceLocation = ($(this).closest('div'));
        currentPieceLocation = currentPieceLocation.attr('id');
    });

    $('.piece').draggable({
        snap: ".square",
        snapMode:"inner",
        revert: true   
    });

    //square is a div
    $('.square').droppable({
        greedy: true,
        tolerance: 'fit',
        accept: function(){

        squareToMove = $(this).attr('id');

        //returns true if square being dropped on is a valid move                        
        return isValidMove(currentPieceLocation, squareToMove);

        },

        drop: function(event, ui) {

            //appends img to the valid square / div
            //this appends ok when I inspect the code
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(event.target));

            //updates internal board
            //this works fine
            makeMove(currentPieceLocation, squareToMove);                
        }

    });

});
```

In a nut shell, I have 64 div's (all have a square class) created with img's for the pieces inside the div's. I have no problem with move validation ( isValidMove() works fine), however, when I go to move a pawn up to the next square in front, the pawn wants to jump up two squares instead. And no its nothing to do with the first pawn move. I disabled that for testing purposes. Now whats interesting is that since I set Revert to "true" instead of "invalid", after I drop the pawn, the pawn tries to move up to what would be the second square in front, then slides back to where I dropped it originally, hence where it should be. Obviously this is probably due to the appending taking place. If I changed Revert to "invalid", then the pawn would just jump up to the second square in front and stay there after I drop it. Even though I can set Revert to "true", obviously we wouldn't want to see the pawn try and slide up and then move back to where it should be.

I have a feeling that the problem is because every div has a square class, when I click on a piece to move the piece / img, isValidMove() is being called due to the starting location div having a square class. I am guessing this might be adding that additional move somehow without me realizing it... I was under the impression that the isValidMove() would be called only when I "DROP" / release the mouse button on a droppable square and not when I just click on a img inside a div containing the class square. As I said I am not experienced with JQuery UI so I'm obviously having some sort of miss understand of how the draggable and droppable are working together. I have seen similar question to this asked, however, none are quite the same. Any help would be great!

Comment: Please dont write an essay.

Comment: A demo we can play with would go a long way - easier to understand what's happening and the ability to debug. You might not need to include the whole chess board (and validation and pieces etc) if you can reproduce the issue using a single piece for instance.

Comment: Now try to move a pawn onto an other pawn with an empty space behind it. It jumps 3 spaces, then moves back to get into the empty space behind the other pawn!

Comment: Yeah I would expect some weird behavior with that as there is nothing validating pawn moves other then it can move forward right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like I figured out the answer to my question, however, I don't think this is a clean (using the clone) way to handling the problem, but it appears to work. If someone else has a cleaner solution to this please feel free to provide it : )

```
$(function(){


    //piece is an img
    $(".piece").mousedown(function() {

        currentPieceLocation = ($(this).closest('div'));
        currentPieceLocation = currentPieceLocation.attr('id');

    });

    //UPDATED CODE: Added helper, start, and stop
    $('.piece').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function() {

        $(this).hide();

        },
        snap: ".square",
        snapMode:"inner",
        revert: true,
        stop: function(){

        $(this).show();

        },
    });

    //square is a div
    $('.square').droppable({
        greedy: true,
        tolerance: 'fit',
        accept: function(){

        squareToMove = $(this).attr('id');

        //returns true if square being dropped on is a valid move                        
        return isValidMove(currentPieceLocation, squareToMove);

        },

        drop: function(event, ui) {

            //UPDATED CODE
            $(ui.draggable).show();
            $(ui.helper).hide();

            //appends img to the valid square / div
            //this appends ok when I inspect the code
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(event.target));

            //updates internal board
            //this works fine
            makeMove(currentPieceLocation, squareToMove);                
        }

    });

});
```

As of right now I have removed any link to the working demo. If someone wants to actually see what the functionality issue was just leave a message and I will put a link back up.